# injecting error manually to form

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to inject error manually to form, I know the way via directive but not sure how can inject error from the controller.

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <form name="createForm">
       <div ng-repeat="item in someItems">
           <input type="text" ng-change="customValidation()" />
       </div>
       <input type="button" ng-disabled="createForm.$invalid" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

controller

```
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.customValidation = function() {
      //do some validation and made createForm valid/invalid based on it
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can do it in two ways.

instead of `Creaeform.$invalid`. You can use some value inside your scope.
You should set the value true or false depending on the validation result of the input. If this doesn't make sense to you, give a comment. I'll give some code.

another way is passing the form object itself to the controller and set the `createForm.$valid = false;` in the controller.